# How to give priority to button

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have 2 buttons, one of which is on top of another.
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/akc6f7 (2 buttons)

Basically, when I click on smaller button in the corner ("?"), I also click on the bigger. How can I make sure that I only click "?" button?

Also, those buttons are `newImageRect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Touch events will fire on the outer most UI element first.

Add `return true` to the end of "?" button touch event to signal that the touch has been handled by the code.

Without the `return true`, the touch event does not know it is handled and subsequently fires on all elements that contain the touch (giving priority to elements outermost elements)

```
function QuestionMarkTouchEvent( event )

if event.phase == "began" then 
    -- Do some stuff
end

return true  -- this tells the program not to fire the touch event again on elements under this.

end
```