# Stacked buttons

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I asked this yesterday, but I guess I didn't really explain well enough. Anyway, I really need help with this...

I have 2 `newImageRect` buttons that I added event listener when tapping. One button is on top of another button and when I click that button which is on top, I also click the one below.

I want to do this: When I click on the button on top, only that button is triggered, but when I click on the button below, but not tapping the one above, only the button below is triggered. So, ALWAYS is only ONE button clicked, never two at once.

Comment: Are you in both cases clicking on both buttons (are these two fully overlapping)?

Comment: Nope, one is really small button on top of another big button (it is actually a help button in the corner of a big button).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238510/how-to-give-priority-to-button/36298693#36298693 all you have to do it return true after the top button touch...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before but somehow when I use this code below I dont see that problem occurring. Not sure if they have solved this issue but after the code I give you two solutions that one I use mainly.

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

local function button1Press( event )
    local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", "BIG", { "OK"} )
    print ("Big")
end

local function buttonHandler( event )
    local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", "Small", { "OK"} )
end

local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    defaultFile = "buttonRed.png",
    overFile = "buttonRedOver.png",
    label = "Button 1 Label",
    emboss = true,
    onPress = button1Press,
}

local buttonArrow = widget.newButton
{
    id = "arrow",
    defaultFile = "buttonArrow.png",
    overFile = "buttonArrowOver.png",
    onPress = buttonHandler,
}

button1.x = 160; button1.y = 160
buttonArrow.x = 250; buttonArrow.y = 160
```

If it doesnt work:

1- On the top button at the end of function returned by the button include "return true". They say this stops the object below the top one receiving the touch event. I had difficulty using this and may not work.

2- If the above doesn't work. Use this simple work around. It simply checks whether the button is already touched or not.

```
lowerbutCheck = true

local function upperButton(event) 
  --your code
 lowerbutChecked=false
end

local function lowerButton(event)
 if lowerbutChecked then
  --do your code
  else
  --do nothing
 end
lowerbutChecked=true
end
```